# Understanding INITPREVNODELIST procedure in John Q. Walker Algorithm (node positioning for a n-ary tree)

Tags: algorithm, layout, tree

I try to understand the *John  Q.  Walker*'s algorithm named "*A Node-Positioning Algorithm for General Trees*" (TR89-034, 1989).

My ultimate aim is to draw n-ary tree with php-svg. (I want to understand the algorithm however, I don't want to copy-paste an implementation even if exists with php-svg.)

I downloaded Walker's algorithm from here: http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/89-034.pdf

I quoted the *very first procedure* (**INITPREVNODELIST**) & his explanations for this procedurefrom his paper below.

**I couldn't understand the inside of the while loop** in INITPREVNODELIST procedure.

For example, if my tree is the example in the paper (I attached it), what is INITPREVNODELIST procedure doing with this tree?

What I understand from this function is:

```
TempPtr is (temporary pointer) an empty array.
LevelZeroPtr is top most starting node. (parent of the tree. Node "0" in the example.)
While TempPtr is not empty
    do something (THIS IS WHERE I COULDN'T UNDERSTAND)
```

**My Questions**

1. Why there is no return statement at the end of the procedure? Is Procedure something different than function? Just a preparation of a variable at the beginning of a class for example? (I am only familiar with class and function terms)
2. What PREVNODE and NEXTLEVEL look like? Using the example tree, can you at least show a partial example for these 2 variables?

Can you help me please? (I am not a software/computer engineer.)

Thank you, best regards

**2 parts below has been quoted from the paper**

```
procedure  INITPREVNODELIST: 
begin 
    (*  Start  with  the  node  at  level  0--the  apex  of  the  tree. *)
    TempPtr  <-  LevelZeroPtr; 
    while  TempPtr  not equal to EMPTY
    begin 
        PREVNODE(TempPtr)  <-  EMPTY; 
        TempPtr  <-  NEXTLEVEL(TempPtr);
    end;
end;
```

Initialize  the  list of previous  nodes  at each  level.  Three list-maintenance procedures,  GETPREVNODEATLEVEL,  SETPREVNODEATLEVEL,  and INITPREVNODELIST.  maintain  a  singly-linked  list.  Each  entry in  the  list corresponds to  the node previous  to  the current node at a  given  level  (for example, element 2  in  the list corresponds to the node  to  the  left of the current  node  at level  2).  If  the  maximum  tree  size  is  known  beforehand,  this  Jist  can  be replaced  with  a  fixed-size  array,  and  these procedures  become trivial. 
Each  list  element  contains  two  fields:  PREVNODE-the  previous  node  at  this level,  and  NEXTLEVEL-a  forward  pointer  to  the  next  list  element.  The  list  is does  not  need  to  be cleaned  up  between  calls  to  POSITIONTREE,  for  performance.

**example n-ary tree in the paper**

[image]

Comment: In case this question is still relevant, here's a link to a Ruby implementation of an improved version of Walker's algorithm. (Walker's algorithm has quadratic runtime whereas the improved one runs in linear time)
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubyvis/Rubyvis/Layout/Tree
and also a JavaScript impl. of another improved version
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16192/Graphic-JavaScript-Tree-with-Layout

Comment: @schnesim in the paper's Summary, Walker claims that the "algorithm operates in time _O(N)_, where _N_ is the number of nodes in the tree". Are you sure it's _O(N^2)_?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why there is no return statement at the end of the procedure? Is Procedure something different than function? Just a preparation of a variable at the beginning of a class for example? (I am only familiar with class and function terms)

A procedure is like a void function/method.

In a modern programming language such as Java, `PREVNODELIST` can be implemented as a `List` of nodes. In the paper, a linked list is chosen. As the algorithm walks the tree, it updates the list to reflect the most recent element visited at each level.

A `HashMap<Int, Node>` would also work:

```java
HashMap<Int, Node> previousNodeAtLevel = new HashMap<>();
```

> 2. What PREVNODE and NEXTLEVEL look like? Using the example tree, can you at least show a partial example for these 2 variables?

In my opinion, these variable names are poorly chosen. PREVNODE is the most recent visited at element at a given level. In other words:

```java
Node prevNodeAtLevelX = previousNodeAtLevel.getOrDefault(levelX, null)
```